# How to characterize the convex hull/closure operator

Tags: convex-analysis

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set)

> Every subset $A$ of a vector space $S$ over the real numbers, or, more generally, some ordered field, is contained within a smallest convex set (called the convex hull of $A$), namely the intersection of all convex sets containing $A$. The convex-hull operator $Conv()$ has the characteristic properties of a hull operator:
>
> - extensive   $S ⊆ Conv(S)$,
> - non-decreasing  $S ⊆ T$ implies that $Conv(S) ⊆ Conv(T)$, and
> - idempotent  $Conv(Conv(S)) = Conv(S)$.

I was wondering what else properties of the convex hull/closure operator has, so that

- we can define a hull/closure operator with such properties to be a convex hull/closure operator, and
- we can define the class of all convex subsets for a given ground set, by for example claiming a subset is convex if and only if it equals its convex hull?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: $Conv(T)=T$ for any affine subspace $T$, and $Conv(S\setminus T)= S$ unless $S=T$.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat: Thanks! I was wondering if these two additional properties can define a closure operator to be a convex closure operator? References are also appreciated.

Comment: Also, $$Conv(X)=\bigcup_{F\subset  X,~F\text{ finite}}Conv(F)$$

Comment: @OlivierBégassat: Thanks! Did you come up with the three properties yourself? Do you know if they can characterize a convex closure operation?

Comment: I have no idea to be honest.

Comment: What the above equation tells us, is that we only need to caracterise the operation for finite sets.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat: Thanks!
 (1) "$Conv(S\setminus T)= S$ unless $S=T$", do you require some conditions on $T$ and/or $S$? (2) in your last comment, is the third property (in your second comment) or all the three properties (in your first two comments) needed for a closure operation to be a convex closure operation?

Comment: In general, closure operators have the properties you listed, though they come in two flavors: hulls and kernels, where kernels are intensive rather than extensive.

Comment: Fyi > in geometry 4 closure operators are widely considered: convex, affine, cone, and linear hulls (spans).

Comment: @alancalvitti: Thanks! (1)I wonder how closure operators "come in two flavors: hulls and kernels"? Isn't it just hulls? (2) "kernels are intensive rather than extensive." How are kernels defined? Do you refer to something like a topological interior operator, or the reduction operator which maps a closed subset to a smallest subset having the closed set as its closure?

Comment: @Tim, the terminology is not really standard, but intuitively hulls are extensive and kernels intensive. For example polyhedra can be defined by half-space intersection (kernel), and dually by  convex/cone hull. Except that nobody really calls the intersection a kernel. (Also, unrelated to kernels of vector space maps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a theorem in van de Vel's [Theory of Convex Structures](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444548610) that may be of interest. First define a closure system. Suppose that $X$ is a set and $\mathcal{C}$ is a collection of subsets of $X$. Then $\langle X, \mathcal{C} \rangle$ is a *closure system* if and only if for all $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{C}$ we have $\cap \mathcal{A} \in \mathcal{C}$. Sometimes people require $\varnothing \in \mathcal{C}$. I can't remember if van de Vel does. For $A \subseteq X$ define $$\mathsf{cl}(A) = \cap \{ C \in \mathcal{C} \colon A \subseteq C \} .$$ In any event the convex subsets of a real vector space satisfy these properties.

**Theorem** Suppose that $\langle X, \mathcal{C} \rangle$ is a closure system. Then the following statements are equivalent:

1. For all $A \subseteq X$ we have $\mathsf{cl}(A) = \cup \{ \mathsf{cl}(F) \colon F \text{ is a finite subset of } A \} $.
2. For all $\mathcal{D}$ which are collections of subsets of $X$ that are directed by inclusion (see below for a definition of directed by inclusion) we have $\mathsf{cl}(\cup \mathcal{D}) = \cup \{ \mathsf{cl}(D) \colon D \in \mathcal{D} \} $.
3. For all $\mathcal{T}$ which are collections of subsets of $X$ that are totally ordered by inclusion (see below for a definition of totally ordered by inclusion) we have $\mathsf{cl}(\cup \mathcal{T}) = \cup \{ \mathsf{cl}(T) \colon T \in \mathcal{T} \} $.

A collection $\mathcal{D}$ of subsets is *directed* by inclusion if and only if for all $D_{0}, D_{1} \in \mathcal{D}$ there is a $D \in \mathcal{D}$ with $D_{0}, D_{1} \subseteq D$.

A collection of subsets is *totally ordered* by inclusion if and only if for all $T_{0}, T_{1} \in \mathcal{T}$ we have $T_{0} \subseteq T_{1}$ or $T_{1} \subseteq T_{0}$.

**Edit**

This is in response to Tim's comment.

Suppose that $X$ is a set and $\mathcal{F}$ is the collection of finite subsets of $X$. Suppose also that $f \colon \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X)$ where $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is the collection of all subsets of $X$. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ define
\begin{align}
g_{n} \colon \mathcal{P}(X) &\rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X) \\
\text{for all $A \subseteq X$ by the assignment} \\
g_{0} \colon A &\mapsto A \\
g_{n} \colon A & \mapsto g_{n-1}(A) \cup (\cup \{ f(F) \colon F \subseteq g_{n-1}(A) \text{ is finite} \} )
\end{align}

Then $A \mapsto \cup \{ g_{n}(A) \colon n \in \mathbb{N} \} $ is a convex hull operator. The function $f$ generalizes the notion of the points between $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$. If you think of this construction in this manner then the $g_{n}$ functions just accumulate line segments.

Comment: +1. Thanks! (1) In the theorem just for a closure system and its closure operator, and there is no convexity structure and convexity closure operator involved? What references is the theorem from? (2) When can a closure operator be a convexity closure operator (in abstract sense)? I guess we will need some properties from a convexity closure operator (in  concrete sense, for a vector space over an ordered field)?

Comment: The result is, more or less, theorem 1.3 in van de Vel's book. Click on [this versionof the book](http://books.google.com/books?id=oDUmytVzSPMC&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=van+de+Vel+Theory+of+Convex&source=bl&ots=v96qZT2g-h&sig=mAjP4ycfZJftnFjuPViVVStOqas&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kNvlUILuI4q2qQG52oFg&ved=0CEQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=van%20de%20Vel%20Theory%20of%20Convex&f=false) The result is on page 5.

Comment: In thm 1.3, he says that a closure operator is a convex closure operator iff it is domain finite. Is a closure operator being domain finite equivalent to $
    \operatorname{cl}(X) = \bigcup\left\{\operatorname{cl}(Y) : Y\subseteq X \text{ and } Y \text{ finite} \right\}$, i.e. finitary property in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator)? So can we say that a closure operator is a convex closure operator iff it has the finitary property?

Comment: (2) [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator#Closure_operators_in_algebra) says "The convex hull in n-dimensional Euclidean space is another example of a finitary closure operator. It satisfies the anti-exchange property: If x is not contained in the union of A and {y}, but in its closure, then y is not contained in the closure of the union of A and {x}. Finitary closure operators with this property give rise to antimatroids." This is a concrete convexity structure, but for an abstract convexity, does its closure satisfy the anti-exchange property? (...)

Comment: (...) Is a closure operator a convex closure operator iff it has both finatary and anti-exchange properties?

Comment: A convex closure operator need not satisfy the anti-exchange property. Suppose that $X$ is a real vector space. For all $A \subseteq X$ let $\mathsf{con}(A)$ be the smallest affine subspace that contains $A$. An affine subspace is a translate of a (usual) subspace. In this case $\mathsf{con}(A) = Y + x$ where $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ and $x \in X$.